# Why won't Castle Windsor just register something?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

```
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .Pick()
            .WithService
            .DefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

That's just one of about seventy different ways I have written this. Not a single one of them works. Nothing gets registered. Ever. If I go ahead and do the explicit registration (Component.For, etc.), this tiny little test application works fine, but I thought, "Hey, let's do this the easy way..."

I've been doing this the "easy" way for an hour. All I have to show for it is:

`Additional information: No component for supporting the service WindsorTestApp.IPrimeSequenceGenerator was found`

Yes, there is a class implementing the interface.

Comment: Does any class in the assembly actually implement `IPrimeSequenceGenerator`?

Comment: Partial answer: implementation of IPrimeSequenceGenerator was named PrimeGenerator, not PrimeSequenceGenerator. Will update if I figure out why the rest isn't working, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Pick()
            .Configure(component => component.LifestyleTransient())
            .ConfigureFor<IPrimeValidator>(component => component.LifestyleSingleton())
            .WithServiceFirstInterface());
```

That totally works now to register everything. The two problems I had were:

1) In order to be automatically registered, the component names have to match the interface names save for the little I in front of the interface name. (IShovel, Shovel, etc.) Edit: your chosen conventions may determine whether or not this is true.

2) The components apparently need to be not only *accessible* to the container, but also *public.* Maybe there are other options that work, but private certainly won't.